# How to upgrade VS2008 reporting Schema from 2005 to 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, reporting-services, reportviewer

As you all know Visual Studio using 2005 schema to create RDLC reports.

SSRS 2008 use 2008 schema to create RDL reports.

So I'm looking for a solution to change VS 2005 schema to 2008 schema. How to do this.

will this issue fix with installing Report Viewer 2010 or not ?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to install Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) from the SSRS2008 install, and then just open the old reports in it, they get automatically updated to the new schema. But this will also mean that your report will no longer run on SSRS2005.

Comment: I'm using BID (actually I have some RDL) I want to convert these rdl files to RDLC files and because of minor schema version in VS 2008 (which use schema 2005 for reporting) I need to change VS schema 2005 to 2008. so there is no need to have BID even because VS use it's own schema and totaly different than SSRS schema which BID use it